# Setting the brightness in windows phone 8

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I need to get the screen brightness and set the brightness of the windows phone in my application which automatically read the screen brightness from the phone and set the brightness of the screen according to the time like during night time the brightness should be less than 50%. How can I do it?

Comment: May I know why that is not possible

Comment: because there is no public api which allows a 3rd party app to adjust the screen brightness.

Comment: Do you speak about Brightness widget?

Comment: Not exactly the brightness widget but I have to create an application which automatically decrease the brightness during particular time according to the user settings

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible with the current SDK.